# Create and loop through javascript "array"

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve the following:
I have an accordion that has a series of tabs within.
Each tab has a series of inputs
When the user changes an input, I want to display 3buttons on the accordion heading to Save, view the pending changes or cancel them.
So far all this is working! Except for the view the pending changes.
On click of the "view pending", I want to scan the tabs, find any inputs that have changed and show there values in a "dynamically" created div below the view button (like a tooltip - NOT as a normal div that is part of the body).

My idea was to create a multi-dimensional array that will store the Tab name, the input name and its value, then loop through the array to build the html to show.

I am stuck creating the multi-dimensional array and how to loop through it once its created.

```
$('#showpending').click
(
  function()
  {
     var a = $(this).siblings('div.accordion-body');
     var b = $(this);
     if ($(a).find('input.sym-changed').length > 0)
     {
        var ma = {};
        $(a).find('input.sym-changed').each(
           function()
           {
              var n=$(this).parent('div.tab-pane').attr('name');//--this to become h2
              var m=$(this).attr('name');//this to be shown as a label
              var v=$(this).attr('value'); //this to be shown as text
              alert(n); alert(m); alert(v);
               //I am stuck here!!!
              ma.n.m = v;
              alert(ma.n.m);
           }
        );
        //build a div based on the array / object 'ma'
        //show the div as tooltip for the button
     }
      else {alert('no inputs found');}
  }
)
```

Here is a jsFiddle that I setup. http://jsfiddle.net/J6ppR/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is an `array [] of objects {}`. It would look like this:

```
[
 { "name" : "test", "age" : 10 }, //index 0
 { "name" : "test1" ,"age": 15 } //index 1
]
```

You could wrap all three things (Tab name, the input name and its value) in an `object` and push it into an array. Gives you more flexibility than multi dimensional arrays. First you declare the array like this:

```
var arr = []
```

Then you could create an object within your each loop, add those three elements you need to that object and and add that object to the array :

$('#showpending').click(function () {

```
       var tabs = $('div.accordion-body').find(".tab-pane"),
           masterArray = [];

       if (tabs.find('input.sym-changed').length > 0) {

           tabs.each(function () {
               var obj = {};

               //tab name
               obj.tabName = $(this).attr("name");
               obj.tabArray = [];


               //key and the value array
               $(this).find("input:text").each(

               function () {
                   obj.tabArray.push({
                       "name": $(this).attr('name'),
                           "value": $(this).val()
                   });
               });

               masterArray.push(obj);
           });
       } else {
           alert('no inputs found');
       }


       $.each(masterArray, function (i, tab) {
           $("body").append("<div id='placeholder'></div>");
           var inputs = function () {
               var inp = "";
               $.each(tab.tabArray, function (i, data) {
                   inp += "<li>" + data.name + " : " + data.value + " </li>";
               });
               return inp;
           }();
           $("#placeholder").append("<h1>" + tab.tabName + "</h1><ul>" + inputs + "</ul>");



       });
   });
```

You could build your object in any way you want, but using objects here is the best way forward in your situation.

**EDIT**

for your current situation, we could use an object of this structure which can be pushed to an array.

```
[
 {
  "tabName" : "details",
  "tabArray" : [
                 {"name": "cust_name", "value" : "Test company" },
                 {"name": "cust_reg_name ", "value" : "Registered " }
               ]
 },

 ..and so on
]
```

by this, it'll also take in as many inputs u give it. Here's your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/J6ppR/6/

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify I would like the resulting html to look something like this:

Comment: `[Shift key] + [enter key]` :)

Comment: Tab name 1 (new line <br>) Input name 1: value <br> Input name 2: value <br> Input name n: value <br> <h2> Tab name 2</h2> <br> Input name: value <br> etc. I don't know how many inputs there may be on a tab (as its generated using ajax as well) nor how many tabs there may be. An object per tab would be better I think?? How would i do that tho?

Comment: Thanks so used to hitting enter for newline ;)

Comment: will the tabs be in order?

Comment: See my answer. I just updated it. I guess it'll work out for u as well

Comment: Thanks heaps! Thats exactly what I wanted. My logic of working from the inputs to find the tab name was getting me stuck i think. Thanks again!

Comment: glad to help.be sure to upvote the answer if u think it'll help other ppl. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Creating a multidimensional array*:

```
a=[];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    a[i]=[];
    for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
        a[i][j]=j;
    }
}
```

*Looping through a multidimensional array*:

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){
        console.log(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```